# Are there any high resolution/scalable (SVG) icons or images available?

Tags: discussion, icons, images

It would be nice to give community-developed apps a familiar look and feel. With that in mind, do the SE sites have any high-resolution or scalable icons and images that we can use?

I'm not really sure if there are any legal implications with using an SE logo in our apps, but I thought I should ask anyway.

Comment: see page footer: `"site design and logo is © 2010 stackoverflow.com llc"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated** Official guidelines are [here](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Icons are [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/347).

Comment: Am I safe if I mention: "...this product uses the StackOverflow API but is not endorsed or affiliated with StackOverflow...?"

Comment: That sentence by itself is OK. But just using that sentence wouldn't mean that you could use the logo.

Comment: Then what *would* allow me to use the logo?

Comment: What if I want to add buttons in my app to connect to SO, SU or SF and I want to put the logo in the button can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** see [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/347) post

This would be very helpful. Though I already used it in mine :)

<strike>I think the key here is to make sure it is clear you are not affiliated with StackOverflow.</strike> (see the new policy)

I think it would be nice to have SVG versions of the logos though.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774/entries/251)  it's fairly large, large enough were you should be able to do things with it.  I have no idea if we are allowed to use them.