# SVG Versions of the Logos

Tags: discussion, images

## [Legal guidelines for using these trademarked Icons](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

### Icons

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/stackexchange.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/stackoverflow.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/superuser.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/serverfault.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/meta.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/stackapps.svg)

[image]
[Download SVG](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/askubuntu.svg)

## Packages

If you want to download a ZIP file with the SVG files and PNG files for many common icon sizes:
[Download ZIP](https://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/icon_pack.zip) -- be sure to [review our official logo usage guidelines](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance) first!

Comment: thanks for putting this together, George. We undeleted it now that we have a policy in place so they can be used correctly!

Comment: @jeff - howzabout splicing in a link to the policy here next to the goodies.

Comment: @Jeff Should be added to the faq.

Comment: Couldn't you have a link to these in the stackauth.com/sites, along side the apple icons, which are great but don't look great when resized.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Can these be added to http://stackexchange.com/about/logos ?

Comment: Are there any plans to release SVG icons for all of the sites, or as @Jonathan. mentions, include a reference to the SVG in the /sites response?

Comment: Hello George, the StackOverflow Icon seems to have a "lite" version with 4 "stacked lines" instead of 6, to use in small icons. It can be seen on SO's favicon, for example. Could you include it here?

Comment: @kikito: I haven't made an SVG version for the "lite" logo.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Bug: The Ask Ubuntu logo doesn't work if the Ubuntu font is not installed. You should convert the "ask" text to a path.

Comment: Also, the "meta" logo here is subtly different in color than the one on meta.stackoverflow.com. This one looks completely flat; the official logo has a slight gradient.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: I'll look into having those issues fixed.

Comment: still not fixed. could you look into that?

Comment: links are invalid

Comment: [Careers 2.0 logo in SVG](https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/8833307)

Comment: I have created StackOverflow's favicon in svg format: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kikito/9178133/raw/552cc00e3deb653c5a4100775167cdd36495306d/stack-overflow-favicon.svg

Comment: How about the new rainbow one ? ;)

Comment: It seems we have new colors for the Stack Overflow logo, and the old *Careers 2.0* logo is gone. https://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Comment: The StackExchange logo has a lot of imperfections. Are they intentional? e.g. Top right lower than top left. Top left has sharp point in radius. Top left of bottom piece has chip taken out of it. Bottom piece seems rotated clockwise (both its top and bottom edge are lower on the righthand side).

Comment: Where can we get all the other logos?