# Link to SVG logo on stackauth

Tags: feature-request, logo

Could you host [SVG version of logo](https://stackapps.com/questions/347) and put a link on stackauth in http://stackauth.com/sites ?

Comment: That would be nice. That would be the final push that would make me switch from using local copies of the logo to using the ones on StackAuth.

Comment: Yep, me too ! :)