# Is there a Stack Exchange icon available?

Tags: support, status-declined, icons

[StackAuth /sites](http://stackauth.com/1.0/help/method?method=sites) route provides all the site's icons except for the one of the Stack Exchange [master](http://stackexchange.com/content/img/logo.png) site.
Could you please provide it in some way (a static SVG would be good)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here it is!**

[image]
Dead link: <del>[SVG version here](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackexchange.svg)</del>

*Note: the same restrictions on this trademarked icon that apply [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos), also apply to the icon above.*

Comment: Links and image are dead. External site is kaput.

Answer (score -1):

No, the `/sites` route is not the right place for that.

`/sites` enumerates all websites that expose API end-points. StackExchange.com does not expose such an endpoint, so it does not (and will not) appear in the results.

Comment: @Kevin uhm, actually i made a mistake to tag my question with feature-request. I was not asking to add the StackExchange icon to the /sites endpoint but to provide it in some way.