# Are there any hi-res versions of SO logo that we can use in our apps?

Tags: support, images

I'd really like either multiple sizes (from icon up) or hi-res or best of all a vector version.  I want my app to look as good as possible and I'm sure SO would want to be well represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SVG Versions of the Logos](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos)

Comment: Thanks... that was so long ago - I almost forgot I made them :)