# Get Site Icon or Icon Url

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Is there a way to get the icon or the IconUrl of the site so I can put it in my app like the DisplayName?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/95/are-there-any-high-resolution-scalable-svg-icons-or-images-available

Comment: Also this: http://stackapps.com/questions/405/acceptable-use-of-copyrighted-logos-names

Comment: DAMN YOU EDIT TIMER! Both Joel's link and mine only cover fair use of the site logos. Robert say's we can use the logos in certain ways. It would be nice for SO to provide an API call that would provide graphics that are open to everyone to use perhaps in various sizes, or in scalable formats. This will be a bigger issue when the SE sites go live.

Comment: I like the idea of an authorized set of official graphics with unrestricted (or nearly so) use.

Comment: I'll point you [here](http://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance) for some legal guidance.  Additionally, some sort of site logo/icon discovery is [status-planned].

Comment: Implementation suggestion: include a "logo" element in the `/stats` API route (it makes sense to go along with "display_name").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The http://stackauth.com/sites method returns a list of all sites in the network, and `/stats` returns a `site` object with logo & icon information (plus more).

Answer (score 2):

The methods stated in the comments are great for pre-defined sites, but in the future there will be new sites that people may want to add to your application immediately (if you have the facility for user-defined sites).

What I did in my app is inspect the index page of the site and scour it for logos (like a favicon, or iPad icon). It works OK, but an official mechanism for this would be better (somewhere in the `/stats/` page perhaps)?

A policy about the use of said icon would also help, stating that you have to write it to your own hosting rather than hotlinking, etc.

(I'm posting this an an answer so that it will bump the question and hopefully get it some attention from the powers-that-be).

Comment: Great idea. In the meantime, feel free to hotlink my icons: http://stackapps.com/questions/347/

Comment: @George, already using them :)

Comment: @George - http://stackapps.com/questions/684/soapi-map-interim-endpoint-discovery-service

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Thanks to George's hard work, there is a quality set of Stack Exchange brand images. I have hosted them and included the path in [SOAPI-MAP](https://stackapps.com/questions/684/soapi-map-interim-endpoint-discovery-service).

As other SE sites get folded in, I will add them to the map along with any graphics made available.

Comment: Hooray! My icons found a home. Are you hosting the SVG files?

Comment: Never mind. I see the icon size parameter.

Comment: @george - the svg icons are there but 1) the naming format breaks the path format and 2) are not typically what would be consumed by an app. If you want SVG, as you probably discovered, images/so-icons/svg/xxx.svg will get them for you.

Comment: Oh, feel free to rename them - I'm planning to add more sizes/formats later.

Comment: And ya, I didn't think there was much use for the SVG files when it comes to web applications.